# Force LibreOffice to open a PDF in Draw?

Tags: linux, pdf, libreoffice, editing, file-format

I'm trying to edit this PDF with LibreOffice Draw. However, when I open it - I get LibreOffice Writer, with text consisting of the initial octets of the PDF file, i.e.

```
%PDF-1.6
%����
2 0 obj
<</Length 4796/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
```

etc. How can I force LibreOffice to actually open the file in Draw? (Or can it just not handle this kinds of files?)

Notes:

- I'm using Debian Stretch GNU/Linux.
- I just installed `libreoffice-pdfimport`, it didn't seem to help.

Comment: I don't know the answer of your question, I just want to ask why you don't use Foxitreader which is very powerful?

Comment: @MyUserName: 1. It looks like a Windows application. 2. It sounds like a reader rather than an editor...

Comment: 1.it is available for different OS . 2.If you get Foxit PhantomPDF, then it is also a very good editor (dont know about the basic version)

Comment: @MyUserName: I guess it's a legitimate suggestion, but this question is about LibreOffice.

Comment: In general, PDF files are **not** editable. There are some sites that can edit a PDF file to a limited extent through a web GUI, but don't expect major changes to look good. You may need a tool to import text from the PDF to Writer, edit the ODS document, and save as PDF.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: That's not true, they're quite editable - they're just not so easy to write an editor for. However, a limited editor - allowing at least for the insertion and manipulation of textboxes and the editing of existing text runs - is very feasible. At any rate, that's not my question was about.